# External API Support in JHipster

Tags: api, jhipster

Hi I'm a newbie to JHipster. I worked in wso tool. Hence, I would like to know if JHipster can support adding the external API (which is a non jhipster application) into the JHipster gateway.

Comment: Which authentication type does this external API expect?

Comment: Ideally it's own authentication like oauth, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JHipster gateway embeds a Zuul proxy that you can configure like this to define custom routes (including to external APIs):

```
zuul:
routes:
    users:
        path: /myroute/**
        url: http://example.com/users_service
```

```

Have a look at the [Spring Cloud](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy) docs for more information.